# How to avoid removing "page" parameter from URI in Django-endless-pagination?

Tags: ajax, django, django-endless-pagination

I use Digg-style Django-endless-pagination with activated ajax support for my project. The annoying thing that it hides parameter ?page=N from URI.

So if I, for example, go back from details page to the general list page it returns me to the first page instead of actual page=N where it comes from.

In case of AJAX deactivation it works as expected and passes "page" parameter to GET. But it disappears right after AJAX activation.

I've changed the string #103 at endless-pagination.js from

```
return false;
```

to

```
return true;
```

Page parameter is passed to URL properly, but it seems at the same time AJAX stopped working forced to reload the whole page when switching between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just added the following string to endless-pagination.js before string #103 return false;
window.history.pushState(3, document.title, context.url);

Now it works as expected.